# Mercurial: create local copy of a remote repository at the remote respository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I use Mercurial on desktops, and then push local repositories to [a centralized server](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Configuring_Apache). I noticed that this remote server does not hold local copies of files in its repositories (the directory is empty, except obviously for the `.hg` one).

What is the preferred way to populate these directories with local copies? (which in turn are used by various unrelated services on that server).

What I came up so far is to use a hook and `hg archive` to create a local copy. This would be a satisfactory solution but I need to configure a per-repository `hgrc` file (which is tedious but I did not find a way to centralize this in `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`). Maybe a global script (in  `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`, run for each changegroup event)? (in that case how can I get the repository name to use in a `if...then` scenario?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get access to the remote repository, you could install a hook for when changegroups come in, and perform an `hg update` when that happens.

A quick check shows this [in the FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ) (question 4.21), but to summarize/duplicate: edit the `.hg/hgrc` file on the remote repository, and add the following lines:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update
```

Whenever the remote repository gets pushed to (or when it performs a `pull`), it will update to the latest changeset.

Some caveats - this may fail if any changes have been made to the files on the remote side (you could use `hg update -C` instead).  Also, if you have pushed any anonymous branches (which you would have to consciously force), you may not update to what you want to update to.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for (I was too much focused on `hg archive`)